# Group Rails query involving Dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making a simple query in rails...

```
@person.visits
```

which gives a list of records...

```
[#<Person::Visit id: 244, date: "2015-02-25", place: "" >,
#< Person::Visit id: 248, date: "2015-02-28", place: "" >,
#< Person::Visit id: 249, date: "2015-03-26", place: "" >,
#< Person::Visit id: 250, date: "2015-03-29", place: "" >,
#< Person::Visit id: 251, date: "2015-04-17", place: "" >,
#< Person::Visit id: 254, date: "2015-04-21", place: "" >]
```

I would like to organise the result to look like this

```
{"February 2015"=>[25,28], "March 2015"=>[26, 29], "May 2015"=>[17,21]}
```

I was trying to use the following, which brings me closer, just not sure how and when to collect dates e.g. [25,28] before grouping them by month.

```
@person.visits.group_by { |d| d.date.strftime("%B %Y") }
```

date is a "Date" field in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct so far, what you have will return a hash of the month and year as the key and the RECORDS in an array that correspond to the group. If you want just the numerical days from those records you have to iterate through it:

```
visits = @person.visits.group_by { |d| d.date.strftime("%B %Y") }

visits.each {|key,value| value.collect! {|rec| rec.due_date.strftime("%d")} }
```

This simply iterates through each member of the hash, takes the array of records and transforms them into just the day portion of the record.

If you want your days to be padded with zeros i.e. "01,02..." use `"%d"` if you want no zeros use `"%e"`

Comment: There may be an elegant way to get  the original query to do this work for you, but I was unable to find it with my limited skills. Something along the lines of querying the records using `.pluck(:date)` to just get the dates returned. Someone else may know how to do this.

Comment: You're welcome. Not sure why you went with a complex if/else solution when Ruby has great methods like `.collect!`. Any particular reason?

Comment: actually, good point. Just a rush decision. I made it work as well, but result was not a hash using ruby methods as well

Answer (score 0):

This is actually kind of a pain to do. I'd not use `group_by`, but construct a hash manually like so:

```
@person.visits.inject({}) do |hash, visit|
  key = visit.date.strftime("%B %Y")
  value = visit.date.day
  if hash[key]
    hash[key] << value
  else
    hash[key] = [value]
  end
  hash
end
```

This will create the desired hash.